# Strange behaviour when using Camino on SF

Tags: discussion

Just lately I'm getting same strange and quite inconsistent behaviour on SF with Camino browser, version 2.0.9 on OS X 10.7. I suspect the problem is with Camino but as it works fine on every other site I visit I can't help but wonder if there's been some recent code change on SF that's at least partially to blame and would like to know if anyone using Camino (is there anyone?) is having issues.

The main issue is that buttons don't always work. e.g. I just posted a comment that would only post by pressing the return key. Clicking the button did nothing.

Using FireFox everything works normally and as I said, Camino works correctly on other sites.

Comment: If I eat bread too quickly while looking at serverfault I get really bad hiccups - maybe I'm in a sub-1%-group too and should just stop doing it :)

Comment: @Chopper3 but what if it's the nicest bread you've ever had and it's been fine for the last few years?

Comment: Assimilate!!!! dunno, good point

Comment: *IIRC* IE, FF, and Chrome are the only three they test with internally before rolling an update (assuming they test the update; which *usually* happens). There's some semi-official feedback mechanism on mSO, but I can't remember where and I'm not going over there unless I have to.

Comment: I had a similar problem on iOS safari but it went away after about 10 mins. Sometimes they break things during updates.

Comment: @Mark, my problem has been happening at least a week. It might have started earlier but I wasn't using the machine for a few weeks prior to that.

Comment: I'm always having trouble with their cdn.stackexchange.com - for about the past 3-4 months. I wonder if they're related. Perhaps some javascript that isn't loading...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We only support recent versions of:

- Chrome
- Firefox
- Safari
- Opera
- Internet Explorer

Anything else, you use at your own risk.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. I wasn't reporting it as a bug, merely trying to find out if others were having the same issue.